# My duplicate-flag was disputed, but the question was marked as a duplicate anyway?

Tags: support, bug, flags, duplicate-questions, disputed-flags

While doing the "First Posts" review queue, I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63860531/nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-destroy-bug-in-python-when-using-tkinter) as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name). That this is correct, is obvious by looking at both questions, and the first question was later closed as a duplicate.

But my duplicate-flag was marked as disputed (see screenshot below). How is that possible? I was the second one flagging it. Looking at the question now, others obviously followed... but in my experience multiple flags are accepted nonetheless. I also can't find an answer to that in [the community wiki post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95277/621177) about disputed flags. My own research showed nothing.

[image: image of flag history of the user with the flag marked as disputed]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The post went through [triage](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/27147464) and the aggregate result of that triage was Looks OK. That result [caused your flag to be disputed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95275/what-is-a-disputed-flag).

I wouldn't worry too much about it, disputed flags don't count against you and you're not going to find everyone agrees with each other about everything here.

> Disputed flags are considered neither helpful nor declined, regardless of the action taken in response to them. They do not affect a user's daily flag count and don't count toward flag bans.

The right result was obtained in the end as a gold badge holder agreed with your assessment and marked the question as a duplicate. Gold badge holders have the ability to mark questions as duplicates all by themselves. So all's well that ends well.

Comment: I don't worry about it, in fact I already knew and linked that in the question. I want to understand how the "right result was obtained" at the end anyway: How did the triangle fail when the duplicate was this obvious? Was it triangled again after multiple other people flagged it? Or did people intentionally press "Looks OK" to flag it themself later?

Comment: Because that would mean, triangles have a loophole allowing harvesting flags from others out of the triangle review queue. But that would be unlikely and a whole other topic... anyway, I think this answer lacks information and therefor I cannot accept it.

Comment: Only the people who pressed Looks OK know why they did that. I'm afraid I can't read minds.

Comment: @NiklasE. Flags are made to help curate the site, not for some kind of personal gain. It's hard to see that it would be worth anyone's while trying steal your correct flags by deliberately reviewing them incorrectly.

Comment: *Update on edit:* The added theorie of a [golden badge user has overwritten the triangle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders) seems plausible. The edited answer is now satisfactory as the acceptabled answer for me.

Comment: @khelwood I couldn't care less if somebody would steel my flags. As you said, you are not gaining something for yourself. I just wanted to point out why the unedited answer wasn't acceptable for me.